# F11-- skipping specific packages on auto-software-update

Tags: linux, fedora, package-management, fedora-11, yum

I recently upgraded my F9 to F11, which went smoothly and has been great-- with the exception of **Amarok** (which at v1.4 is an OUTSTANDING music program-- I like it MUCH better then iTunes).

F11 supports the new v2.2 of Amarok, which frankly stinks... but never fear, there is wonderful chap who built and posted F11 packages of v1.4 (http://users.linpro.no/ingvar/amarok/)... which I have installed and have happily running.

Enough background-- now to the Q. Is there some way to feed an exception list to the Software Updater, so that it doesn't even TRY to update my Amarok (and I don't forget and accidentally nuke my lovely v1.4)? Perhaps something in **yum.conf**?

Thanks in advance to all fellow Linux fans who respond!

Happy New Year everyone!

Thomas
(F11 happily humming on my ThinkPad Z61 -
helping me crank out web technology in
Python/Django & PHP)

Comment: This message should be on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I'd say here is pretty suitable. This isn't specific to servers really, a lot of people use Linux on the desktop. Not to mention he's trying to exclude amarok updates, most people don't even install music players on servers.

Answer (score 2):

You can put an exclusion into yum.conf. Add a line like this:

```
exclude=amarok*
```